# Lazyload: How to deal with internet connection lost?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Im using Lazysizes and trying to do something if user lose internet connection and keep scrolling, then there is no image shown
How can i make if images are failed to donwload to replace them with src image?
i tried to put in src loading image and replace on error but is not working because it return error again and again ...

```
document.addEventListener('error', function(e){ if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){e.target.src = e.target.getAttribute('src')} }, true);
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
 <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $preloader?>" data-src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive lazyload" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML for those images as well?

Comment: @iamdlm topic edited

Comment: If you don't have internet connection you can't show the src image, since you can't download it.